# How to Consume Kafka Topic from ZeroCode Framework

Tags: testing, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, zerocode

I want to consume one kafka topic via [ZeroCode](https://github.com/authorjapps/zerocode) framework. I can consume my localhost kafka server from ZeroCode scenario. Also I can consume the topic that is got from my actual remote kafka server with using kafka-consumer.bat via command line but I can not consume same topic from ZeroCode.

What Do I need to add special configuration?

```
{ 
  "name": "Consume Message From doob-ship-topic",
  "url": "kafka-topic:my-sample-topic",
  "operation": "consume",
  "request": {
    "consumerLocalConfigs": {
      "recordType": "JSON",
      "commitSync": false,
      "showRecordsConsumed": true,
      "maxNoOfRetryPollsOrTimeouts": 3
    }
  },
  "assertions": {
    "size": 1,
    "records": [
      {
        "value": {
          "key": "99930000000000260001"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I tried different configurations but I didn't handle with that.

Answer (score 0):

I solved.

```
    "consumerLocalConfigs": {
      "recordType": "RAW",
      "commitSync": true,
      "showRecordsConsumed": true,
      "maxNoOfRetryPollsOrTimeouts": 2,
      "pollingTime": 1595  // I added this.
    }
```

Added pollingTime is solved my problem.